# America/Central time in MySql is not saving right time

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to save my records as Central time in my `MySql` database. But it looks like the time is wrong.

```
Field: added_on
Data type: TIMESTAMP
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**PHP:**

```
$now = date('Y/m/d H:i:s' );
$date = new DateTime( $now, new DateTimeZone( 'America/Chicago' ) );

$sql = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO agent_notes
            (agent_code, account_code, agent_note, added_on)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" );

$sql->execute( array( $agent_code, $account_code, $agent_note, $date ) );
```

I am referring to https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php#114172

At the time of posting CST current time was `2:36 am, Wednesday, 29 April 2020`
Date saved in the database on my server was `7:36 am, Wednesday, 29 April 2020`

While I was expecting it to be the same as CST above, i.e., `2:36 am, Wednesday, 29 April 2020`

**Server: GoDaddy**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "At the time of posting CST current time was 2:36 am, Wednesday, 29 April 2020" No it wasn't. That was the current *Central* time, or *CDT* at the moment. *CST* (Central *Standard* Time) is UTC-6, which was 1:36am, but that's not being observed in Chicago at the moment. Now, it looks like what was actually saved was the UTC timestamp - which is entirely reasonable for a TIMESTAMP data field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's storing the correct value: the timestamp in UTC. If you want to convert that back into your local time zone when you fetch the data, you can do so, but a `TIMESTAMP` field in MySql doesn't have a time zone.

From the [MySql TIMESTAMP tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx):

> When you insert a TIMESTAMP value into a table, MySQL converts it from your connection’s time zone to UTC for storing.

Likewise from the [reference documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.

So if you're *fetching* the data from the database using a connection which specifies the time zone, you should get it back in that time zone - but if you just browse the database in some other way, or if you fetch it *without* specifying a time zone in the connection, you'll get UTC.

That's entirely appropriate for a timestamp. It's [not always appropriate for *future* dates and times](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/), but that's a different matter.